# How to change the title attribute for the WP logo image on wp-login.php

Tags: admin, urls, wp-login-form

This is how I change the url for the WP logo on the `wp-login.php` page:

```
function my_login_url() {
    $url = esc_url( home_url() );
    return ( $url ); 
}
add_filter('login_headerurl', 'my_login_url');
```

But the title for the a tag remains the same.

How to change the a tag too?

I mean right now I have this:

```
<a href="http://localhost/demo" title="We are using WordPress" tabindex="-1">DEMO</a>
```

And I want:

```
<a href="http://localhost/demo" title="My custom text" tabindex="-1">DEMO</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function my_login_logo_url() {
  return home_url();
}
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'my_login_logo_url' );

function my_login_logo_url_title() {
  return 'Your Site Name and Info';
}
add_filter( 'login_headertitle', 'my_login_logo_url_title' );
```

[For details follow link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form)

Comment: Wow, thanks. It works. Any idea how can we combine them into one function?

Comment: @JohnDoerthy These are two separate tasks. [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) **requires** two different functions.